# One sub-category can belong to many category

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

This is a diagram of the category-subcategory table (adjacency model).

[image]

Now, a sub-category like printer paper can have more than one category (office supply and computers), I believe, but the model above is rigid and unsupportive, this won't let me do the one child two parent thing.

What do I do? Is there an example of something like this out there?

Comment: You need a many to many relationship. 
This is usually achived by introducing a new table to the schema, that is connected with a one to many relationship to both tables. However, since you have only one category table, you need the relationship table to be connected twice to the category table.

Comment: Like having a category, sub-category and a category-subcategory table?. Three tables?

Comment: [_Tips_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) on many:many mapping table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest, removing `parent_id` from `category` table.

Create a new table for relationships with columns

1. parent_id
2. category_id

Sample data in relationships table

```
parent        | category
office_supply | printer_paper
computers     | printer_paper
```

Ofcourse, you will be storing the category_id in the table and not the names :)

Comment: bhai like having three tables, one for category, subcategory and category-subcategory table with category_id and subcategory_id?

Comment: @Manish - A slight variation to that, I am not suggesting a different table for `subcategory`. If you want to define `printer paper` as a sub category, I would suggest keep an additional field in `category` table for `isSubCategory?`. You only need two tables, `category` and `relationships`

Comment: can you point me to an example so that I have a better view. Koi example hai to link post kar de

Comment: @Manish The [link](http://www.joinfu.com/2005/12/managing-many-to-many-relationships-in-mysql-part-1/) has information on Many to Many relationships, have a look at that. Also, for the benefit of others on the website, Kindly refrain from use of any other language apart from English, since the answer and the discussions linked to it can help other people as well. :)